# Laravel 5: how to create controller with method name

Tags: laravel-5, controller, laravel-artisan

I am new to Laravel 5 and gone through https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers but could not find any way in which i could create controller using php artisan with a specific method name. I tried below options but none of them work.

```
php artisan make:controller HomeControler#index logout
```

and

```
php artisan make:controller HomeControler/index logout
```

and

```
php artisan make:controller HomeController index logout
```

Is it possible in Laravel 5 to achieve this? If yes, is it also possible to declare more than one function while creating controller using artisan make command?

Comment: I dont believe it is possible to do this with default artisan. You may want to create a package with copies the artisan command and adds the functionality.

Answer (score 6):

```
php artisan make:controller HomeControler --resource
```

The controller will contain a method for each of the available resource operations:

- index
- create
- store
- show
- edit
- update
- destroy

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i do not want to create resource controller. I want to create only one or two specific methods in my controller. For Example, i want to declare index and logout method while creating HomeController. How would i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate Controller  and specified the name of method which will be generate. The only way to generated controller with all CRUD methods It is when you generate a resource based controller

> php artisan make:controller PersonController --resource

The other way is to generate Controller which is empty